# access location with google maps

Tags: android

I want to access my location using google maps and I don't know why it doesn't work.

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

that is what appears when I rule the emulator:[image]

Now I try to learn sth about maps, but in final I want to press on a button and to apear in google maps the location of a restaurant or sth else. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Complete Code for accessing device location (not including the maps key part which i think you have already done)

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
     {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public Location mLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

    super.onStop();

}


public void onConnected( Bundle bundle) {


    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLocation != null && mMap != null) {
        LatLng tun = new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude());

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(tun).title("Marker in Sydney"));


    }


}

         @Override
         public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

         }
     }
```

you have to write this code in the manifest.xml as well

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

this will allow app to be able to use device's location

The only thing that remains is that you MUST do GRANT the access of the Location by going to the settings of the app in the permissions menu Allow App for GPS location in other case it will not show the location

Comment: I cannot rezolve "LocationServices", do you know why?

Comment: dude, sorry but i am new on stack and also on android studio. I just copied your code over my code and made that change to manifest.xml. My code consist in what you send earlier

Comment: have you implemented everything like i did in the MainActivity.java DUDE?

Comment: import android.location.LocationListener;

Comment: where i find settings of the app? btw still doesn't work.

Comment: import android.location.LocationListener;
have you imported this copy and past this at the very top of your code

Comment: and now what was the error ?
can you somehow send me your androidstudio screen

Comment: i will to put a prt screen here, i will post like an answer

Comment: double click on that error and than send me again the screenshot where i can see the line where the error occurs besides delete that  import part of location services which i send you earlier you have already done that

Comment: dude listen         compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
 gradle.app dependencies copy past the line

Answer (score 0):

'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
you have to compile play services in order to access LocationListener

Comment: so that is a new import

Comment: it is not an import in java file you have to write this code in your app grade in the part of dependencies

Comment: i already had this 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'

Comment: send me the screenshot of your gradle:app

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the acces location permissions in the manifest

Comment: yes, one of the answers contain the permissions and i copied there